# matlab live simulation of differential equations

Tags: matlab

I need to run an interactive simulation of two differential equations of the shape:

```
der(x)= A  * x + c1 * y
der(y)= c2 * x + c3 * y
```

where der(x) is the time derivative of x

But I need to be able to change `A` while the simulation is running in real time.

I'm new to matlab, but I poked around a little so I'm not a total noob

Comment: If `A` varies continuously with time, it is not a parameter but actually a function, `A(t)`. Maybe you need re-derive your equations. Or does `A` just change at a few key points in time? You should also show what you have tried in order to illustrate what you're trying to do or this will surely get closed/downvoted.

Comment: `A` is the user input to the system, it's actually a nuclear reactor point kinetic equations and `A` is the control rod inserted reactivity

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I have done this in the past. Depending on whether you are using Matlab's `ode` functions or your own, different things might be easier.

If you are plotting figures in real time and using your own ODE solver, you can run you solver over a single timestep, plot results and use a `keyPressFcn` to modify parameters. This is my preferred method, and it works like this: Start by opening your figure window

```
figHandle = figure('KeyPressFcn',@keyControl);
```

then run your ODE solver, one timestep at a time and plot results. The `keyControl` function looks like this:

```
function keyControl(varargin)
    cmd = get(figHandle,'CurrentCharacter');
    switch double(cmd)
        case 30 % up arrow for example
    end
end
```

If you are using Matlab ODE solvers, you can use an `OutputFcn` to modify some data (although this can be a little clunky).